# How to perform math operation on numbers in string of python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, operation

How we can perform mathematical operation on string in python.

Consider below example

```
with open('/home/akashk/projects/math.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

for x in content:
    print(x)
    print(type(x))
```

output is like

```
1abc0+5*1hv0
```

I want to perform operation using operand and operators

above should be considered as 10+5*10 = 60
In short remove characters and perform mathematical operation on operands.

eval('10+5*10') which gives 60 but it will not handle characters.

Comment: The output is `0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. Use the **isalpha** method to remove all alpha chars and the use **eval**

**Ex:**

```
s = "1abc0+5*1hv0"
s = "".join([i for i in s if not i.isalpha()])
print eval(s)
```

**Output**:

```
60
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh for this answer, this solution solved my problem,

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
eval('10/2%2-1')
```

The result is 0.

Comment: recommending `eval` without the security caveat??

Comment: Thanks for answer but eval works only with integer, I want to perform operation with more complexity

Comment: @MrT I am reading txt file, variables are not pre-defined & don't want to consider while calculations

Comment: @MrT Whats your problem? My question is clear already, you considered a = 2.7 and something which has no any relation to my question. Why you are interested in my question even if you don't understand the question properly and not able to answer my question.